# How to parse PNR Captcha to get PNR status.?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, xmlhttprequest

I have a PNR Inquiry app on Google Play. It was working very fine. But recently Indian Railwys added captcha to their PNR Inquiry section and because of this I am not able to pass proper data to the server to get proper response. How to add this captcha in my app in form of an imageview and ask the users to enter captcha details also so that I can send proper data and get proper response.

[Indian Railways PNR Inquiry Link](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html)

Here is my PnrCheck.java which I was using earlier. Please help what modifications should be done here..

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpClientConnection;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ExecutionContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestConnControl;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestExpectContinue;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestTargetHost;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestUserAgent;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class PNRStatusCheck {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String pnr1 = "1154177041";
            String reqStr = "lccp_pnrno1=" + pnr1 + "&submitpnr=Get+Status";
            PNRStatusCheck check = new PNRStatusCheck();
            StringBuffer data = check.getPNRResponse(reqStr, "http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_pnrstat_cgi.cgi");
            if(data != null) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                PNRStatus pnr = check.parseHtml(data);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public StringBuffer getPNRResponse(String reqStr, String urlAddr) throws Exception {
        String urlHost = null;
        int port;
        String method = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlAddr);
            urlHost = url.getHost();
            port = url.getPort();
            method = url.getFile();

            // validate port
            if(port == -1) {
                port = url.getDefaultPort();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
        HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, "HttpComponents/1.1");
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

        BasicHttpProcessor httpproc = new BasicHttpProcessor();
        // Required protocol interceptors
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestContent());
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestTargetHost());
        // Recommended protocol interceptors
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestConnControl());
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestUserAgent());
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestExpectContinue());

        HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();
        HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(null);
        HttpHost host = new HttpHost(urlHost, port);
        DefaultHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultHttpClientConnection();

        context.setAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_CONNECTION, conn);
        context.setAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST, host);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String resData = null;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String statusStr = null;
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            String REQ_METHOD = method;
            String[] targets = { REQ_METHOD };

            for (int i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
                if (!conn.isOpen()) {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), host.getPort());
                    conn.bind(socket, params);
                }
                BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest req = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest("POST", targets[i]);
                req.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(new ByteArrayInputStream(reqStr.toString().getBytes()), reqStr.length()));
                req.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                req.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7");
                req.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
                req.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
                req.setHeader("Origin", "http://www.indianrail.gov.in");
                req.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
                req.setHeader("Referer", "http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html");
                //req.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
                req.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
                req.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");


                httpexecutor.preProcess(req, httpproc, context);

                HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(req, conn, context);
                response.setParams(params);
                httpexecutor.postProcess(response, httpproc, context);

                Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
                for(int j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
                    if(headers[j].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ERROR_MSG")) {
                        resData = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    } 
                }
                statusStr = response.getStatusLine().toString();
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                if(in != null) {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                }

                String line = null;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buff.append(line + "\n");
                }
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return buff;
    }

    public PNRStatus parseHtml(StringBuffer data) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        if(data != null) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.toString().getBytes())));
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        String line = null;
        TrainDetails trainDetails = new TrainDetails();
        List<PassengerDetails> passDetailsList = new ArrayList<PassengerDetails>();
        PassengerDetails passDetails = null;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.startsWith("<TD") && line.contains("table_border_both")) {
                line = line.replace("<B>", "");
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf("\">")+2, line.indexOf("</")).trim();

                if(line.contains("CHART")) {
                    trainDetails.setChatStatus(line);
                    break;
                }
                if(i > 7) {//Passenger Details
                    if(passDetails == null) {
                        passDetails = new PassengerDetails();
                    }
                    switch(i) {
                    case 8 :
                        passDetails.setName(line);
                        break;
                    case 9 :
                        passDetails.setBookingStatus(line.replace(" ", ""));
                        break;
                    case 10 :
                        passDetails.setCurrentStatus(line.replace(" ", ""));
                        i = 7;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(i == 7 ) {
                        passDetailsList.add(passDetails);
                        passDetails = null;
                    }

                } else { // Train details
                    switch(i){
                    case 0 :
                            trainDetails.setNumber(line);
                            break;
                    case 1 :
                            trainDetails.setName(line);
                            break;
                    case 2 :
                            trainDetails.setBoardingDate(line);
                            break;
                    case 3 :
                            trainDetails.setFrom(line);
                            break;
                    case 4 :
                            trainDetails.setTo(line);
                            break;
                    case 5 :
                            trainDetails.setReservedUpto(line);
                            break;
                    case 6 :
                            trainDetails.setBoardingPoint(line);
                            break;
                    case 7 :
                            trainDetails.setReservedType(line);
                            break;
                    default :
                        break;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        if(trainDetails.getNumber() != null) {
            PNRStatus pnrStatus = new PNRStatus();
            pnrStatus.setTrainDetails(trainDetails);
            pnrStatus.setPassengerDetails(passDetailsList);
            return pnrStatus;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Please help what changes in the code shall be made to get the status now. Thanx all in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After analysing the server you are targeting, you can change your code like this :

```
String captcha = "37819";
String pnr1 = "1154177041";
String reqStr = "lccp_pnrno1=" + pnr1 + "&lccp_cap_val=" + captcha + "&lccp_capinp_val=" + captcha + "&submitpnr=Get+Status";
PNRStatusCheck check = new PNRStatusCheck();
StringBuffer data = check.getPNRResponse(reqStr, "http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_pnstat_cgi_28688.cgi");
```

They are sending the captcha to the client and when you submit the form they are waiting for both the captcha that they send plus the value that the user entered !!! :)

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I will surely check it and reply back asap.

Comment: I am sorry Rida.. Its still not working. And its really disappointing that I am not getting any other reply on this question as well.

Comment: I have updated my code, test it and it's working. They have change the url to `http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_pnstat_cgi_28688.cgi`, but I think that your pnr `1154177041` is no longer valid ;)

Comment: any news, have you test it ?

Comment: No luck Rida. But you are right about the URL. Thank you very much for that. I did not notice that.

Comment: That's what I said, your PNR is not valid even if you try it manually in their site, both methods (java code & manually) gives the same output `FLUSHED PNR / PNR NOT YET GENERATED`. That's means that the java code is working ;)

Comment: Can you give me a valid PNR ?

Comment: So, can you give me a valid PNR to prove that my solution is working ! Or you admit it already.

Comment: Rida its not working. If you don't believe, give me your mail ID, I will send you full project zipped file. Proper PNR is 6623639027. Check its not working. If its working for you, tell me your mail ID and I will forward you whole project and check its not working.

Comment: @AtulDhanuka here is the data I get from the server : Journey Details
Train Number Train Name Boarding Date 
(DD-MM-YYYY) From To Reserved Upto Boarding Point Class
*11448 SHAKTIPUNJ EXP 22- 3-2014 SGRL JBP JBP SGRL  3A ... . So it's working :) please ask a new question to get your response, maybe you have another problem

Comment: Can you please give me your mail id and have a look on my project once. May be you find something missing in that.? My mail ID is j.akshatzz@gmail.com, if you can , please drop a mail and I will reply you back with my project.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the captcha ***answer*** from the html text:

```
<span id="txtCaptchaDiv" style="background-image:url(1.jpg); text-align:center; border:none;
     font-weight:bold; font-family:Modern font-size=12">59747</span>
```

The background is given by the image at http://www.indianrail.gov.in/1.jpg , you can just ignore it :)))))

(HOWTO: open the page in google chrome, right-clich on the captha and choose "Inspect Element").

UPD:
try something like

```
//StringBuffer data
int start = data.indexOf("<span id=\"txtCaptchaDiv\"");
int middle = data.indexOf(">", start);
int end = data.indexOf("</span>", middle);
String captcha = data.substring(middle+1,end);
```

Comment: In java, you have to locate that string in the xml source. Or parse the output and get it from the parsed stuff.

Comment: see the UPD. It's just finding a substring.

Comment: But how to update this captcha in the above given java file.? I tried but no results.? Can you please help me modify the above java file so that a proper http request is sent.?

Answer (score 0):

If we use the above mentioned method we will get the **empty("")** String. That is because if we look into the generated HTML, we will find this:

```
<span id="txtCaptchaDiv" style="background-image:url(1.jpg); text-align:center;            
border:none;font-weight:bold; font-family:Modernfont-size=12></span> 
<input name="lccp_cap_val" value="78358" id="txtCaptcha" type="hidden">
```

To extract the value of captcha  we can use this

```
    int startOfSpanTag = data.indexOf("<span id=\"txtCaptchaDiv\"");
    int endOfSpanTag = data.indexOf("</span>", startOfSpanTag);
    int posOfValueAttr = data.indexOf("value=", endOfSpanTag);
    int startPosOfDoubleQuote = data.indexOf("\"", posOfValueAttr);
    int endPosOfDoubleQuote = data.indexOf("\"", startPosOfDoubleQuote + 1);
    String capatcha = data.substring(startPosOfDoubleQuote + 1, endPosOfDoubleQuote);
```

I hope you must have found the answer till now. If you have better solution please share your comments !!!!!.